# Limit of $\ln(x)-\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\pi²}{6} - \sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x²}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I did my best to get the notation correct but it is likely wrong so let me explain. The sum on the right tends to $\frac{\pi²}{6}$. As it is incrementally getting closer to $\frac{\pi²}{6}$ I want to see what the delta is to $\frac{\pi²}{6}$ and I would like to sum those deltas. I noticed this sum is a very close approximation to $ln(x)$ but it tends to be off by ~.0677. The 0677 is the limit of where my excel skills can get me but I want to find out if this actually tends to a specific number or if it goes up forever. I have gone through $x=1$ to $1,000,000$. Is there a way to put this into wolfram alpha?

$$\ln(x)-\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}( \frac{\pi²}{6} - \displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x²})=?$$

Comment: The notation doesn't make much sense...both summations are over the same variable, so the summation is not well defined.

Comment: Are you rather after something like $$S_n=\ln(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i^2}\right)\ ?$$ Then this is also $$S_n=\ln(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty\frac{1}{i^2}$$ and one can indeed show that, $S_n$ converges to a finite limit when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notation does not make much sense, but trying to interpolate your actual question you seem to ask about the value of the limit
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\zeta(2)-H_k^{(2)}\right)\right]$$
where by summation by parts
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}H_k^{(2)} = n H_n^{(2)}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}=(n+1) H_n^{(2)}-H_n $$
such that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\zeta(2)-H_k^{(2)}\right) = n\left(\zeta(2)-H_n^{(2)}\right)-H_n^{(2)}+H_n. $$
Now $\lim_{n\to +\infty}H_n^{(2)}=\zeta(2)$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(H_n-\log(n)\right)=\gamma$. By Cesàro-Stolz
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\zeta(2)-H_n^{(2)}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}=1$$
hence 
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\zeta(2)-H_k^{(2)}\right)\right]=\color{red}{\zeta(2)-\gamma-1}\approx 0.0677184.$$

Comment: Sir, could you please give a look on this question of mine and provide some help -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145071/limit-of-a-function-given-the-recurrence-relation

Answer (score 0):

Using Jack D'Aurizio's solution, we end with
$$S_n=\log(n)+H_{n+1}-(n+1)\, H_{n+1}^{(2)}+\frac{\pi ^2 }{6}n$$ Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers, this leads to
$$S_n=\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\gamma-1\right)-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{5}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Moreover, this gives a quite good approximation of $S_n$; for example, 
$$S_{10}=\frac{3586319}{254016}-\frac{5 \pi ^2}{3}+\log (10)\approx -0.0282788$$ while the above expansion leads to
$$-\frac{263}{240}-\gamma +\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\approx -0.0281149$$